# Dynamic Filtering of Calculated Table Not Working with SELECTEDVALUE(slicer) in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

What do you guys think why does not work the following code if I give dynamic value for a slicer which used as a VAR in a calculated table measure?

**UPDATE:**
The calculation works with hard coded index (like 1.151) but doesn't if using a slicer and a dynamic measure **SelectedPowerIndex =
(SELECTEDVALUE(powerIndexes[pt_index]).**

**I've created a calculated table in 2 two steps.** *The code example is only a short filtering producing the same problem.*

The calculated table shortly (1) CALCULATETABLE( SELECTCOLUMNS( using selected_index variable at the end, (2) GROUPBY( using X row aggregation from the table created in step 1.

The result is a 3 column table showing as many grouped row as the index gives. Index is for example 1.151, which works if hard coded, not works if dynamic.

If I use slicer of a **dimension-table** (*powerIndexes*) to select 1.151, the calculated table is not shown. **The slicer is okay, it shows 1.151 in a card if slicer is choosen.**

**SHORT EXAMPLE CODE PRODUCING THE SAME PROBLEM**
The second one gives nothing back however 16 rows data in the table with 1.151.

---

```
thisWorks= 
VAR filtered_table = 
    FILTER(
        globalDatas,
        globalDatas[pt_index] = 1.151
    )
RETURN filtered_table
```

---

```
thisNotWorks= = 
VAR selected_index = [SelectedPowerIndex]
VAR filtered_table = 
    FILTER(
        globalDatas,
        globalDatas[pt_index] = selected_index
    )
RETURN filtered_table
```

---

I used SelectedPowerIndex = SELECTEDVALUE(powerIndexes[pt_index])
The powerIndexes is a one-column table created in Power Query from pt_index column of globalDatas table and there is a one-to-many relation in Power BI between powerIndexes and globalDatas.

It should work fine. The code is a calculated table but I rewrote it with a normal FILTER function resulting the same nothing.

Comment: Is this a calculated table you are creating?

Comment: do you have filter context in the visual? Meaning, is the index anywhere in the visual or as a report slicer? If you only return the the selected_index var, does it return blank?

Comment: @zach updated the question section highlighted the importance. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @davidebacci yes it is a calculated table, I updated the question :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated tables do not work with slicers. Calculated tables are computed at refresh time.